# Ubuntu 20.04 - waking up from suspend mode causes monitor signal to be lost

Tags: 20.04

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 with GTX970 GPU, 16GB RAM and when I suspend the system and wake it up my monitor loses signal and I have to reboot my PC and lose my entire session. Does anyone know any solution to this problem or is it a known issue?

Comment: Are you using the recommended Nvidia drivers?

Comment: I am using NVIDIA driver metapackage from NVIDIA-470. Is it a recommended driver? How do I check what driver is recommended for my Ubuntu distro?

Comment: Open Additional Drivers (or Software & Updates > Additional Drivers).

Comment: It says This devise is using the recommended driver.